# Zxing Error While running Scan Test

Tags: iphone, ios, zxing, barcode-scanner

'text' may be deprecated because receiver type is unknown in **ZXingWidgetController.m**

`[self presentResultForString:[twoDResult text]];

  [self presentResultPoints:[twoDResult points] forImage:image usingSubset:subset];

  [self performSelector:@selector(alertDelegate:) withObject:[[twoDResult text] copy] afterDelay:0.0];
  decoder.delegate = nil;`    please help

Comment: Where is twoDResult declared?

Comment: i have downloaded the [zxing barcode](https://github.com/joelind/zxing-iphone) file from github and trying to run the scan test but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Issue 1198](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1198).

This was closed as CannotReproduce because I haven't been able to, well, reproduce it.

The comments indicate that it might not be an issue in svn or even in the 2.0 release. (But I haven't been able to figure out what "code modernizer" means.)

The github repo you mention hasn't been updated in years. You're probably better off using https://github.com/zxing/zxing which is updated automatically from svn every few minutes.

Comment: can you please help me with barcode scanner app which uses Zxing Library for scanning the Barcodes